# How to get public/private key from cacert.pem

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509

i has download cacert.pem from internet, but how to get cacert.key ?

How to get public/private key from cacert.pem ?

Comment: Why would they give you the private keys? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i try to set my nginx configuration, i set key for "ssl_certificate      cacert.pem", but what key set for "ssl_certificate_key"

Comment: This was answered in your other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348948/where-can-i-download-cacert-key.

Comment: Public key allows you to crypt your message so that only owner of the associated private key could decrypt the message.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

A certificate only carries its public key and other information of the certificate. As per standard, it never contains public key. It is the responsibility of the owner of public key (subject in the certificate) to save the private key securely.

Since, you have downloaded the public key and it is not your key, you need to do some cryptanalysis to get the private key.

From the certificate, you can always get the public key since it is public.

You can get the public key by following command:

```
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -infrom PEM -pubkey -out temp>output
```

Delete the temp file. In output file, it contains public key in PEM form.

Answer (score 0):

The command should rather be (-inform instead of -infrom)

```
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -inform PEM -pubkey -out temp>output
```